# Mongodb: find items in array and their last record

Tags: mongodb

I have many device record, each record has the deviceID、data、updatetime...
there is a deviceArray which contain some deviceID.
I want to find all device record in array but only show the last updated record.

I try this query:

```
collection.find({ 'deviceID': { $in: deviceArray }},{ _id: 0, }).sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(1).toArray(function (err, devicedata) {
                            console.log(devicedata);
                        });
```

but it only show one record...

I search for  $last (aggregation) at official web, but I don't need use group command..

I want the result like

```
[{deviceID:1 , data:xxx, updatetime:xxx},
{deviceID:2 , data:xxx, updatetime:xxx},
{deviceID:3 , data:xxx, updatetime:xxx},
]
```

when my devicearray is [1,2,3]

how can I query it? thanks for your help.

Comment: try sorting on updatetime field eg: sort({updatetime :-1})

Comment: Hi: Shubham : sort by updatetime  only show one record,too.

Comment: cause u are using limit 1

Comment: Shubham: yes because  I only want every device's last data, if I remove limit 1, it will show all records..  but it seems only show the last data.

Comment: You can try `collection.aggregate([{$match:{ 'deviceID': { $in: deviceArray }}},{$sort:{deviceID:1, updatetime:1}}, {$group:{_id:"$deviceID", data:{$last:"$$ROOT"}}}, {$sort:{_id:1}}])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $match: { "deviceID" : { $in: [1,2,3] }} },
    { $sort : { "deviceID" :-1, "updatetime" : -1 } },
    {
        $group: 
        {
            _id: {deviceID:"$deviceID" }, 
            lastUpdatedRecord: 
            { 
                $first:  
                { 
                    deviceID: "$deviceID", 
                    data: "$data", 
                    updatetime: "$updatetime" 
                } 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$lastUpdatedRecord" }
    }
 ]).toArray(function (err, devicedata) {
                            console.log(devicedata);
                        });
```

For this sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ea53cc5d430def261c0622"),
    "updatetime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:37:17.620Z"),
    "deviceID" : 1.0,
    "data" : "AAAAAAA"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ea53cc5d430def261c0623"),
    "updatetime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:42:17.620Z"),
    "deviceID" : 2.0,
    "data" : "BBBBBBB"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ea53cc5d430def261c0624"),
    "updatetime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:45:17.620Z"),
    "deviceID" : 3.0,
    "data" : "CCCCCCC"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ea53cc5d430def261c0625"),
    "updatetime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:50:17.620Z"),
    "deviceID" : 1.0,
    "data" : "DDDDDDD"
}
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "deviceID" : 1.0,
        "data" : "DDDDDDD",
        "updatetime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:50:17.620Z")
    },
    {
        "deviceID" : 2.0,
        "data" : "BBBBBBB",
        "updatetime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:42:17.620Z")
    },
    {
        "deviceID" : 3.0,
        "data" : "CCCCCCC",
        "updatetime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:45:17.620Z")
    }
]
```